# Exporting points according to a route I made

Tags: point, line, route

So I work on a ship and get given a shape file with points on it and I am required to make a vessel route out of this.

The problem is that once I have created a route between all the points and export them as a shape or csv, they are not arranged according to the route, but the way they were sent. I then have to manually arrange them in Excel.

For example: I am sent the points in order of A C D B and the route goes A B C D, however when exported it is still A C D B.

I assume I have to link the point and line feature somehow, but not sure how.

Software on the vessel is QGIS.

Comment: Thanks I changed it. We usually work with anywhere from a 100 to 800 points. It's a diamond exploration vessel. QGIS is more user friendly so I would stick with QGIS. Basically the office sends me a bunch of random locations and I then have to create a route out of them. However I need the locations according to the route as I have to put it in other softwares as well as print and distribute these points to various departments on the vessel. It has to contain the points name, water depth, distance to next sample, sediment thickness and co-ordinates. So it's not just 1 set of attributes.

Comment: Rather than exporting in a specific order, I'd recommend adding a column that will contain the order, which can be sorted on which is much more reliable. Not sure how you're building the routes, so not sure of the best way for you to add the order value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Extract vertices` on route layer
2. `Join attributes by location` to join the extracted vertices to the point layer
3. `Order by expression` to order the output by the field `vertex_index` that was created in step 1
4. Delete the fields not needed

If your route is not perfectly snapped to your points you might need to add a buffer step between step 1 and 2.

[image]